# Cancelling all print jobs not working

Tags: printing

I thought this cleared all printing jobs?

cancel -a -x

I also used CUPS to cancel all print jobs, yet the printer wants to print.

The printer has no paper, so I don't waste a page of paper.

The printer is a Canon TS9100.

What's up?

Comment: The printer itself may have a print queue which needs to be canceled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the data has already been sent to the printer. If this is the case, you need to cancel the print job at the printer itself.

According to the [TS9100 manual](https://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/Manual/All/TS9100%20series/EN/UG/ug_o_01_01.html), you can press the "stop button" on the printer to cancel printing a queued print job.

Comment: Thanks mchid. Have a good evening.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to cancel all print jobs.

`lprm -`

if you happen to need to specify destination for the `lprm -` command you can get the address of your printer from `lpoptions` or better yet `lpq -a` as that will show you all queued jobs from all printers.